# Error join table with lambda expression c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables and I want join them with a lambda expression.

The code looks like this:

```
  var maintenance = maintenanceService.GetAll();
  var mDetail = maintenanceDetailService.GetAll();

  var data = maintenance.Join
  (
      mDetail,
      m => m.Id,
      md => md.MaintenanceId,
      (i, m, md) => new VehicleFuelReportViewModel 
                    { 
                       MaintenanceDate = m.MaintenanceDate 
                    }
 );
```

I get this error:

> Error 12  The type arguments for method 
>       'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join
>       (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, 
>        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, 
>        System.Func, 
>        System.Func, System.Func)'
>        cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

`maintenance` and `mDetail` are `IEnumerable<>`. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: `Join` expects both tables to have the same schema.

Comment: Why are you joining if you're not using any data from the second table?

Comment: it just an example @DStanley

Comment: @RichardSchneider No it doesn't - you can join tables with different schemas, pulling different columns from either table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class NewVehicleFuelReportViewModel
{
   public int Index { get; set; }
   public MaintenanceDate { get; set; }
}

var data = maintenance.Join(mDetail,
   m => m.Id,
   md => md.MaintenanceId,
   ( m, md) => new VehicleFuelReportViewModel { 
      MaintenanceDate = m.MaintenanceDate 
   });
   int i = 0;
   var dataWithIndex = data.select(d=>{
   var tempdata = new NewVehicleFuelReportViewModel();
   tempdata.Indx = i++;
   tempdata.MaintenanceDate = d.MaintenanceDate;
   return tempdata;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: The i parameter is used for an increment , so i have a number of data , if i remove it there isn't an error anymore but i need a number column

Answer (score 0):

There is not an overload of `Join` that takes an index parameter in the third lambda.  If you need a number column in the result then do a subsequent `Select`:

```
var data = maintenance.Join(mDetail,
   m => m.Id,
   md => md.MaintenanceId,
   (m, md) => m.MaintenanceDate)
                      .Select((i, m) new VehicleFuelReportViewModel { 
      MaintenanceDate = m.MaintenanceDate,
      Index = i}) ;
```

Although I'm confused why you're doing a `Join` if you're not using any data from the joined table.  Did you mean to do a count of related records?